# Вывести путь к файлу который в данный момент использует DOS в заголовок окна

Tags: windows, bat, dos

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода пути, где лежит файл, в заголовок окна CMD на XP и более новых ОС.

Попробовал реализовать вывод директории при помощи создания следующих файлов

Оба лежат на диске C:\ и через реестр вызывается через AutoRun cmd.bat

После чего был создан батник для вызова DOS-программы и отправлен на рабочий стол.
Дело в том, что путь к файлу DOS-программы прописывается в заголовке, но не меняется с переходом внутри этой программы по разным файлам. Помогите пожалуйста, как можно решить? Спасибо огромное :)

```
--------------------------------------- C:\cmd.bat --------------------------------
doskey cd = cd /d $* ^&^& "C:\cmd_title.bat"
title %cd%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------- C:\cmd_title.bat --------------------------
@echo off
title %cd%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Так при вызове другого батника рабочий каталог не меняется, значит заголовок окна меняется на прежний - остается тем же. Значение текущего рабочего каталога в переменной -  %cd%. Логика соблюдена, на что тогда жалуетесь?

Comment: не знаю как переписать, все перепробовал :D

Comment: не понятно, чего Вы добиваетесь? Полный путь исполняемого в данный момент batch-файла хранится в соответствующей переменной **%~df0**. А каталог - **%~dp0**. Пример: **echo %~dp0**

Comment: Добиваюсь смены названия заголовка окна консоли, на путь к исполняему в данный момент DOS программой файла. При чем при переходе на другой файл заголовок тоже должен меняться.